# Equilateral triangles $ABX$ and $CAY$ are described on sides $AB$ and $AC$ of a $\triangle ABC$ externally to $\triangle ABC$. Prove that $CX = BY$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Equilateral triangles $ABX$ and $CAY$ are described on sides $AB$ and $AC$ of a $\triangle ABC$ externally to $\triangle ABC$. Prove that $CX = BY$.

I constructed the following figure for it.

[image]

I am not able to proceed any further. How could I do this?

Comment: I suppose that the second triangle is $CAY$, or not?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $\triangle ACX$ and $\triangle BAY$ are equal to each other:
$$|AC|=|AY|, |AX|=|AB|$$and $Â$ in $\triangle BAY $ is equal to $Â$ in $\triangle ACX$ because $\triangle ABX$ and $\triangle ACY$ are equilateral triangles.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- What would you get if you were to rotate point $X$  around $A$ counterclockwise by $\frac{\pi}{3}$?
- What would you get if you were to rotate point $C$  around $A$ counterclockwise by $\frac{\pi}{3}$?
- What would you get if you were to rotate $\triangle ACX$ around $A$ counterclockwise by $\frac{\pi}{3}$?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the origin and $z_2, z_3$ complex numbers representing $B, C$ respectively. $Y$ is $z_3e^{ipi/3}$ and $X$ is $z_2e^{-i \pi/3}$.
\begin{align*}
CX = |z_3 - z_2e^{-i \pi/3}| = |e^{-i\pi/3}(z_3e^{i\pi/3} - z_2)|=|z_3e^{i\pi/3} - z_2| = BY
\end{align*}